# my blog crashes ie7?

Tags: themes, errors, debug

weird problem. My blog theme works fine in ie8, ie9 and all other major browsers...

however ie7 doesn't even render it? in ie7 it seems like my blog even has serverside problems?
[image]

any idea what could cause that? In my programming history i've encountered ie7 styling issues and stuff but never something like this that the webpage doesn't even get rendered? Sometimes the page is kind of loaded in ie7, however the browser does crash anyway.

any idea what could cause that?

If sometimes the page gets loaded in ie7 the bar at the bottom says: "loaded but with errors" ... I do not have a single error if I validate the page!

Comment: Are you using this browser on a separate computer? Does Chrome or FF work on this separate computer? Sounds like the actual client is having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a javascript error on line 451: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery. and then Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden): axx1cxj-b.css. The second one looks like s stylesheet that typekit is trying to load.

Comment: well, thank you, didn't think of that? typekit is enabled for the real domain and this is just a testrun on my personal website. I commented typekit out and it seems there are no more errors. However ie7 is still crashing - anymore ideas?

Comment: sorry, that's all I've got. it doesn't crash IE8 in IE7 mode, so I've got no way to see the behavior.